# Use Pagination (until, since) in Reading Open Graph Objects

Tags: facebook-graph-api, action, paging

Is using `until` or `since` available when reading Open Graph actions?

```
http://graph.facebook.com/me/appname:action/object?since=yesterday
```

References:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, see: Paging
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/#read